# Trouble getting a serial connection communicating between C# and C

Tags: c#, c, serial-port

I have a microprocessor running C code and a computer running C# code.  I am trying to get them to communicate through a serial connection (System.IO.Ports.SerialPort).  I have no problems connecting, rather problems communicating.

In C# I have code like this to send the string "rr\n":

```
mySeiralPort.WriteLine("rr");
```

In C (on the microcontroller), I have code such as this to receive the string:

```
gets(str);
```

Note that the STDIN stream is the serialport stream.  Here's where things get interesting.  As a test, we have a bit of code that causes an LED to light up if `str` is equal to "rr".  This allows us to observe whether or not the microcontroller has received it as expected.

When using HyperTerminal, I can type "r", then type "r", then press enter -> and the LED lights up, signaling it has indeed read "rr" from the serial stream.  However, when I use the above `WriteLine` function from C#, we get no such result.

I believe this boils down to the functionality of HyperTerminal sending character-by-character, and that the `gets()` function reads character-by-character until it encounters a newline.

Can anyone shed some light on how to get C#'s `WriteLine()` and C's `gets()` functions to work together?

Comment: Can you get the microcontroller to write back out whatever it receives? Looking at that exact output might you give you some hint as to what the issue is.

Comment: The first thing to check is your port settings (baud rate, flow control, etc). Capture a HT session using [PortMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644); then capture a session with your program and compare.

Comment: +1 @Stephen Cleary for mentioning PortMon

Comment: PortMon won't monitor this particular port, citing that it's "in use".  I would love to write back what the Micro received, but the way we're receiving it is with the gets() function, which isn't working.

Comment: @Adam: start PortMon monitoring before your program (or HT) runs.

Comment: Might want to make sure .net has actually sent the data down the serial line and not left it in the buffer.

Answer (score 3):

The classic mistake is forgetting to turn the handshake signals on, either by enabling hardware handshake or by setting the SerialPort.DtrEnable and RtsEnable properties to true.  Serial port devices should ignore anything until they detect the other end powered up and ready to receive.

Less likely is that the microcontroller isn't responding fast enough to received bytes.  Either because it is slow to respond to the interrupt or is using polling.  That can cause a receiver overrun error with loss of the received byte.  Lowering the baudrate would fix that.

Comment: Or turning on handshaking when it shouldn't be.

Comment: While I appreciate your input, we also checked all those things.

Comment: Hmm, if you checked if the controller responded quickly enough to interrupts then you should already know why it doesn't work.

Comment: I design PC to MCU RS-232 interfaces all the time, and I have yet to encounter a MCU that is more sluggish than a PC when it comes to responding to RS-232 commands. Even an 8-bit MCU with horrible ineffective architecture, like 8051, running at 1MHz or so, will be laughing and running in circles around your "slow" intel-multi-core-i7-fluff PC. Simply because the MCU doesn't come with Windows.

Comment: @Lundin - you just haven't encountered the programmer yet.

Comment: @Hans If the MCU fails to respond faster than Windows because of software, then the person who wrote the MCU program should perhaps not call themselves 'programmer'.

Comment: @Lundin: Apparently your MCU doesn't do much with the data.  Sure, you can shave a few microseconds off the response latency compared to my software on Win7, but I can do digital filtering and pattern recognition that would leave that MCU crying uncle.

Comment: @Ben The pure delay time between RS-232 messages should be enough for your MCU to do pretty much anything. Even if you run at one of the fastest baudrates, lets say 115200bps = 8.68us/bit, and send only 20 bytes of data, you would have 8,68us*20*10 = 1.73ms of time to blow while the messages are transferred. In that much time you can execute *anything*, assuming you made a somewhat sane choise of MCU for the purpose your application. I wouldn't exactly attempt digital filtering on a 8051.

Comment: Btw, PC:s don't know what microseconds are. Attempt anything with faster response time than 10ms on a Windows PC and it will be guaranteed to fail. Plus it is no RTOS so Windows can merrily freeze for several minutes after receiving a command, if it feels like it.

Comment: @Lundin: "can merrily freeze for several minutes"... this is 99% FUD, with really horrid third-party drivers lending just a hint of truth.  The only time my Win7 computer is unusable for minutes is when Windows installs an update that has to be configured during boot.  You might try doing I/O from an above-normal priority thread on a Windows machine (that's not overloaded), you may be surprised by the response time.  (And including the message transfer time in the response time is not kosher, processing can't start until the message is received).

Comment: @Lundin: Nevertheless, your statement about "sane choice of MCU for the purpose" is correct, I'm just saying that for some purposes a Core i7 might be one of the better choices.

Answer (score 1):

HyperTerminal may be (probably is) using a different newline character from C#.  Try writing "rr\r" or "rr\n" instead of using `WriteLine`.

Comment: I checked the NewLine characters, they are all using the same.  Interesting enough, the gets() function is not terminating, meaning it isn't encountering a "\n" character, even though I am sending it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using an oscilloscope or logic analyzer to help determine the problem? If you work with embedded systems, these tools are essential. Using these tools can tell you what the WriteLine method is doing or not doing compared to HT.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a buffering problem but it could also be related to what the microprocessor expects as an end of line terminator. Is HT sending newline only or carriage return followed by newline?

First of all, determine what the microprocessor expects for end of line. Then use Write instead of WriteLine and write the individual bytes, in ASCII. Remember that .NET likes to use UNICODE but a microprocessor probably expects ASCII.

Maybe you sent Unicode bytes or maybe you sent a carriage return character that was not expected and was concatenated to the RR.

Note that this class has an attribute called NewLine. You may be able to get WriteLine working by setting it correctly. There is another attribute called encoding. Do you have it set to ASCII?

Comment: +1 For some simple and logical ideas, like your buffering problem idea.

Answer (score 0):

C# might be sending 2 bytes for each `r` (eg UTF16), whereas Hyperterminal is probably just sending 1 byte for each `r` (eg ASCII).

Might want to look at [strings in c#](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx) for information on how they are encoded.

Comment: Strings are encoded in memory as UTF-16, but they are re-encoded appropriately by the `SerialPort` class.

Comment: Well there is nothing in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.writeline.aspx to say it encodes.